# How to convert string to int to fit in a if statement

Tags: java, android

Since adding image to the sqlite DB is a bust I might as well just add some other things on my quiz app.

I have this quiz app where I want to have an if else statement when the user gets 4 below it will have a sad sound effect and 5 above it will play a happy sound effect.

I know how to do that (I hope so) but the thing I don't know is how do I convert a string back to int in order for me to accept it in a if statement.

1. CoinValue here is first declared as an int

```
    int coinValue = 0;
```

2. However it is then turned into a string in a later code

```
 coinText.setText(String.valueOf(coinValue));
```

*I already tried some codes earlier but it just gives off an error.

3. I then have an intent to get the score then transfer it to the results page

```
intent.putExtra("score", coinValue);
```

Once it is transferred to the results page it's already a string right? It all works I just want to make the coinValue an int so when It goes to the results I can code it to the if statement.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(coinText.getText());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at your question the answer for how to convert a String to int has already been mentioned as a comment by @Elliot using `Integer.parseInt(coinText.getText());`, but there's something else I would like to mention.

you said

> 2. However it is then turned into a string in a later code

Well not really, the coinValue is still an integer and you just set it as a String into the TextView coinText. Meaning it remains as an int with no changes in its original value and only its value is used as a String to set in the textView, that's all.

So now when you use

> `intent.putExtra("score", coinValue);`

This is adding an integer value as an extra to the intent you are passing to the results page. which you will have to retrieve using

```
getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0);    //where 0 is the default int value. you may change it as you require
```

So basically you coinValue remains an int and it is that integer value you are passing to results where you retrieve it and proceed without a need for conversion from String to int.

Hope this was of some help to you..

Comment: Thanks so I was just have a wrong understanding in the codes lol. 
new problem: the code I have in gameWon class is         score = getIntent().getExtras().get("score").toString(); however it doesn't work when I try to do if (score >=5) it says that the operator cannot be applied to the string

Comment: Well if you read my answer I mentioned you can get integer from intent easily using ```getIntent().getIntExtra("score", 0); ``` anyways what your line ```getIntent().getExtras().get("score").toString();``` does is convert the retrieved value to String. So use ```int score = (int)getIntent().getExtras().get("score");```

Comment: You can't use ```if(score >= 5)``` if score is String, you can either declare it as int and use the method i mentioned above. Or keep everything as it is where you declared score as String and use ```if(Integer.parseInt(score) >= 5)```